# Memory Management - WorstFit vs. BestFit algorithms

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I understand the idea behind both BestFit and WorstFit memory schedulers.

I am wondering which approach yields the lowest time in the job queue.

Since WorstFit slows the rate at which small holes in memory are made, does that mean that it will result in a lower average job queue wait time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer. For future viewers, Worst Fit maintains, on average, a lower job queue time. It is a direct result of the characteristic of Worst Fit.

With a minimal memory compaction approach (only compacting empty frames who are both adjacent in memory and in the linked list), Worst Fit postpones creating slivers of empty memory.

However, with a more complete memory compaction algorithm (compaction adjacent frames in memory irrespective of their location in the linked list), Worst Fit and Best Fit will operate almost identically. While they choose their frames differently, the OS will always work harder to compact memory and create empty spaces to allocate to incoming processes.